# debugging python code while doing unitest using ipdb ResourceWarning

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, ubuntu-18.04, ipdb

I have a python code that workes well on Ubuntu 16. I installed Ubuntu 18 and now when I try to debug the code while doing unitest I get the following warning each time I press 'n' or 's':

```
ipdb> /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:618: ResourceWarning: unclosed event loop <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
  source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I use python 3.7.5

How do I get rid of this warning? Its impossible to work like that

Comment: I'm having this issue on osx. upgraded my python to 3.8.1 and am still getting this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Running with `python -W ignore script.py` worked to get rid of this while debugging.

Comment: Not really a solution but a useful workaround. Other warnings might be important.